# Zoom in on text within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I created a `iframe` containing text, and I added a zoom feature that zooms in on the `iframe` using:

`document.getElementById("textarea").style.zoom = percentage;`

However, when I use that to zoom in, it makes the `iframe` "bigger" but the size of the text within the it remains the same. How can I zoom in on the text specifically?

Comment: did you try using transform scale instead of zoom? `document.getElementById("textareathingy").style.transform = 'scale(percentage/100)';`. Not sure if this will work but you can try once.